# nodejs or angular shows jade file content and doesn't render it (at ng-include)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug

I have a problem with `ng-include` where a  `jade` file called to render. I put the `jade` file in public/partials folder, but when I load the page it show me the content of jade file not a rendered one.

**sharedElement.jade:**

```
div
  Name
  input#Name(name="Name" type="text")
  Family 
  input#FamilyName(name="family" type="text")
  button(type="button") submit it
```

**index.jade:**

```
div(ng-include='"partials/sharedElements.jade"')
```

"out put html is"

```
<div ng-include="&quot;partials/sharedElements.jade&quot;" class="ng-scope">    
    <span class="ng-scope">
       div
         Name
         input#Name(name="Name" type="text")
         Family 
         input#FamilyName(name="family" type="text")
         button(type="button") submit it</span></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Out put shows:**

```
div Name input#Name(name="Name" type="text") Family input#FamilyName(name="family" type="text") button(type="button") submit it
```

Where I miss something?

Comment: but the `ng-include` is a wrapper for get method + angularjs `$compile`, can you compile the file on get request?

Comment: I test it now... But result is same as out put! So what's the problem here?

Comment: I believe that file included by ng-include should be already compiled, why dont you use jade `include`? Is this ng-include going to have dynamic value?

Comment: Yes, it has dynamic value and I should use it. I don't understand your mean of compiling the jade file... When we run node app it compile all file at first... Am I right?

Comment: AFAIK no, it does compile the JADE files on request but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The jade view engine (in Express that I assume you're using) does not understand the `ng-include` directive as its a feature of AngularJS. You must set the ng-include value to the path that you've configured to return a rendered partial. Something like partials/sharedElements.

And in your express app you should have something like:

```
app.get('/partials/sharedElements', function     (req, res) {
  res.render('partials/sharedElements', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

This is obviously just to give you an idea. You didn't specify how you render your Jade stuff in your express app.

Have a look at the Express docs on template engines. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: I understood! But the major problem that forced me to use `ng-include` was loading a `jade` into a `div` element. As you say I can call a get method and use it in my `angular` controller... but then how should I load it into the `div` element? I don't know any other standard way unless using `jquery`.